# logging additional info in default php logs

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Please don't fire me for asking what seems to be a simple question. The code is probably written badly by the coders (me included).

`php.ini` has `error_log = /writeable_path/php_errors.log`
Every script includes `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);` via `auto_prepend_file` in `php.ini`

the `php_errors.log` file shows, for example,

```
[21-Mar-2020 20:26:23 Asia/Kolkata] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from' at line 1
```

Which is all well and good... but how do i include `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in this, for example?

I searched high and low, and I don't think it is possible without writing my own custom error handler and trapping all errors and include that via `auto_append_file`, for example

Any thoughts??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You answered your own question, a custom handler. Not everything uses a web server so there may be context where a URI doesn't apply.